# Como transformar errors E_PARSE em Exception no PHP?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

O PHP tem um ótimo recurso que permite converter os erros que podem ocorrer numa aplicação em `Exceptions`. Isso pode ser feito através da classe `ErrorException`

Exemplo:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);

});

try {
   $a = $b;
} catch(\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Undefined variable: b

}
```

Essa "captura de erros" funciona perfeitamente para errors como `E_NOTICE`, `E_WARNING` e etc... Porém, quando ocorre um **Parse Error** (`E_PARSE`), o `set_error_handler` não é capaz de capturá-lo.

Eu consegui  (mais ou menos) fazer essa captura do `E_PARSE` através da função [`register_register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.register-shutdown-function.php) (ela executa uma função quando o php ao finaliza o script, mesmo se houver interrupção da execução por conta do `E_PARSE`) em combinação com a função [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-get-last.php).

1. Gostaria de sabe como proceder para fazer essa operação, de maneira
   que ocorra semelhantemente na captura de erros com o
   `set_error_handler`.
2. Como proceder se exibir na tela somente o erro (e não códigos
   anteriores a execução). Vou ter que usar um `ob_start` combinado com
   um `ob_end_clean` dentro do "capturador" do erro?

**De antemão já digo:**
Dizer que não há maneira de fazer isso é mentira, pois o `Laravel 4` consegue perfeitamente transformar o `E_PARSE` em exceção também!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Atualização

A pedido do usuário @gmsantos, estou postando o código da transformação do `E_PARSE` para `ErrorException`, que eu acho que seja o mais próximo do que eu estou querendo.

Isso foi o que eu consegui fazer utilizando o `register_shutdown_function` (foi bem rápido, por isso não tem nenhuma orientado a objetos :) ):

```
<?php


ob_start();

echo 'Olá mundo'; 

// Por essa função, o try/catch consegue "pegar" a exceção
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){

    // Se o cara não colocar arroba, o erro é mostrado :)

    if (error_reporting() !== 0) {

        ob_clean(); // limpa o buffer e não imprime "Ólá mundo"

        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);

    }
});

// aqui não dá pra usar try/catch :(

register_shutdown_function(function(){

    // O register_shutdown_function só pode capturar E_PARSERs provenientes de include, e não no mesmo script

    if ($err = error_get_last()) {

        ob_clean(); // limpa o buffer e não imprime "Ólá mundo"

        throw new ErrorException($err['message'], 0, $err['type'], $err['file'], $err['line']);

        /*
            Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '.'' 
            in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\teste.php:4 

            Stack trace: 

            #0 [internal function]: {closure}() 

            #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\teste.php on line 4
        */
    }

});

// Proprositalmente para gerar uma exception não capturada pelo set_error_handler

$a = @$a;

try {

    $b = $b;

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage(); 


    /*
        Se a variável "a" tiver um arroba colocado, essa mensagem é impressa!
        Nesse caso captura a exceção retorna: Undefined Variable: b
    */

}


try {

    include 'teste.php'; 

    /* 
        Esse include gera um E_PARSE, porém só é exibido no catch se for outros tipos de erro, 
        pois o register_shutdown_function é executado só quando o script é encerrado :(
        Não consegui capturar com o "catch"
    */

} catch(\ErrorException $ee) {

    echo $ee->getMessage(); // Esse não imprime nada, como dito acima
}
```

Apenas reforçando o que já está escrito no exemplo: Não há maneira de capturar o `E_PARSER` no `try/catch` (pelo menos, nesse script que eu fiz, não tem como)

Comment: Na verdade não é o Laravel que faz isso, mas sim os seus componentes de debug. Já tentou investigar o código fonte do [whoops](https://packagist.org/packages/filp/whoops) (Laravel 4) ou [symfony/Debug](https://github.com/symfony/Debug) (Laravel 5)?

Comment: Agora que eu sei quem é o responsável (segundo sua informação, @gmsantos), vou dar uma pesquisada sim. Valeu!

Comment: caso encontre a resposta poste aqui pra gente por favor ;)

Comment: veja esse método no whoops: https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/9e1ffa25c32db969b6ce0db73290ea272d896b11/src/Whoops/Run.php#L331 . Acho que é algo como você tinha dito, manipulando o output buffer.

Comment: Gosto muito do PHP. Mas, se fosse uma linguagem totalmente orientada a objetos (e mais organizada), não teria que fazer tantos **paranauês** (leia "gambiarras" para alguns casos), para conseguir fazer algo que em outras linguagens é bem mais simples de fazer!

Comment: PHP: ame-o ou deixe-o :) . A linguagem está em constante evolução e bastante coisa pode mudar (Leia-se HHMV, Hack e PHPNG)

Comment: rsrsrsrsrsrs! é só um desabafo! eu não vou deixar o PHP não, ele paga meu salário.

Comment: ve esse comentário no site do PHP deve ajudar na sua implementação http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php#84345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de dar `throw` no `ErrorException` dentro do callback do `register_shutdown_function`, você pode construir um `ErrorException` e passá-la para um handler que cuidará dos detalhes.

```
<?php
function handleException(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function handleError(array $error = null) {
    $err = error_get_last();

    if ($err) {
        $exception =  new ErrorException(
            $err['message'], 
            $err['type'], 
            1,  
            $error['file'], 
            $err['line']
        );
        handleException($exception);
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('handleError');
```